# Maven Skip A Module For Release

Tags: maven

I am performing a release for my project using `release:perform`, here is my command:

```
mvn -B clean release:prepare -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dresume=false" -Dresume=false release:perform
```

I want to skip some module what's the way to do it using command line. can we use `-pl '!skipmodule'` ?

Comment: @Guillaume can I use `-pl` command ?

Comment: I've not tried it myself but that's what one the answer says

Comment: Why would you like skip modules? That means the do not belong into the multi module build...